# Запись таблицы HTML в CSV или JSON файл

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv

У меня есть HTML таблица, которую пользователи заполняют на странице, нужно что бы при добавлении данных на страницу, они дублировались в CSV или JSON файл.
Можно ли разместить в каком то пространстве (типо гугл диска) CSV или JSON файл и записывать туда мою таблицу?

Вопрос первый, где можно хранить файл?

Вопрос второй, как записывать ?

Вот JavaScript код, где я скачиваю файл CSV, нашла только такое.

```
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + '\uFEFF' + prob.map(e => e.join(";")).join("\n");
  
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
alert(encodedUri);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); 
link.click();
```

Помогите пожалуйста))) Очень нужно)))

Comment: Обычно все такие действия делает серверный ЯП... Сам клиент не особо располагает возможностями по записи чего-либо на носители. Может в локальное хранилище записать или куки... Но это все будет доступно только на компе, где такое записали. На остальных компах этих данных не будет. https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Comment: @ksa Спасибо !))

Comment: @ksa Я почитала, что могу использовать PScript,  не знала, что к HTML могу подключить питон, так как почти не работала с HTML. Через  РScript можно такое реализовать, не знаете? Что бы сразу понять, что изучить)

Comment: Я с `РScript` дело не имел...